# How to read Facebook Insights for a Native/Desktop app programmatically

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication, facebook-audience-network

Unfortunately I'm struggling to understand the documentation provided by Facebook.

This is the scenario:
- Some of my iPhone Apps are also registered as Native/Desktop Apps on Facebook in order to support the Facebook Audience Network.
- I'm building a tool in python which will retrieve data from the reporting API in order to run some automated analysis on specific metrics (request, impressions and so on).

The question is: how do I retrieve this data?

The documentation for the reporting API is here: [Reporting API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reporting-api)

However I'm struggling with the access token.

It says that I could use the specific App Token available here: [App Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/)

However by using such token, I get an error saying that app tokens can't be used for Desktop/Native Ads.

What is the correct way to do it then? Here is where I struggle to understand Facebook Documentation.

My guess is that I should use a User Access Token instead, generated for a user that is also the admin of the App for which I want to retrieve the insights.
What really freaks me out is that apparently, this can't be done with normal HTTP calls only but it requires instead to go through the Facebook Login Dialog. I also need to create another Facebook (web) app because there is no way to get a simple "User Object"... Everything needs to start and go through a registered Facebook App. And there's no way to go through these steps by using backend code only.

So... to recap... in order to read the Insights for a Native/Desktop Facebook App (APP_A), I have to:
- Create a new Web Facebook App (APP_B)
- Create a web interface somewhere for APP_B) which will trigger the Facebook Login Dialog and request the read_insights permission.
- Login through this web interface and generate a User Access Token
- Put this User Access Token in my backend code and run the scripts that retrieve the data provided by the Reporting API for APP_B

Really... to me... it doesn't make any sense to create a new Facebook App in order to access the data of another Facebook App.

Isn't there another better, simpler, quicker, cleaner way to achieve the same final result?

Comment: Have you tried using a user access token for an admin of the app whose insights you want to read? Once you have the read_insights permission this should work with no issue - I think you're going to have to use a user access token here because the other methods would involve trying to work around the basic security model of the API

Comment: Yep... Probably it wasn't clear in my question but that's exactly what I was trying to get someone to confirm. However, how do I generate a user access token then? I think I answered myself again in the question. What I find strange is that I need to create a second "external" web app in order to generate a user access token and that it can't be done only with server calls or a server-to-server authentication system.

Comment: You can do it with the first app, or any app at all really, but to read insights on behalf of someone via the API ( in this case the app admin) you need to go through the login process with that user and have them grant you read_insights permission - that an app token (excluding those from native/desktop apps which may have put the app secret in their code) can also be used to fetch insights is an exception rather than the rule

Comment: Ok, thanks! I thought I could access the app insights directly somehow. I believe that doing it on behalf of a user introduces a degree of complexity which is not necessary.
But I guess is down to the fact that a Facebook App can't be a standalone object but always belong to a "real" user instead. Thanks for your input. Really appreciated. If you want to make it a proper answer, I will up vote it and mark as accepted. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Stephen, I've just realised that you work at Facebook and you also looked after a bug report on the Facebook Audience Network SDK that I sent a few days ago. :) I just wanted to say thanks! :)